# remove particular word from a list

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

My list is given below -

```
mylist = [("aaaa8"),("bb8_null"),("ccc8"),("dddddd8"),
         ("aaaa8"),("hsd"),("ccc8"),("abc_null"),
         ("tre_null"),("fdsf"),("ccc8"),("dddddd8")]
```

I want my final list should be like -

```
final_list = [("aaaa8"),("ccc8"),("dddddd8"),
         ("aaaa8"),("hsd"),("ccc8"),
         ("fdsf"),("ccc8"),("dddddd8")]
```

I have done so far -

```
final_list = [i.replace('_null', "") for i in mylist]
```

But it's not working

Comment: `final_list = [i for i in mylist if not i.endswith('_null')]` ?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you need `str.endswith`.

**Ex:**

```
mylist = [("aaaa8"),("bb8_null"),("ccc8"),("dddddd8"),
         ("aaaa8"),("hsd"),("ccc8"),("abc_null"),
         ("tre_null"),("fdsf"),("ccc8"),("dddddd8")]
final_list = [i for i in mylist if not i.endswith('_null')]
print(final_list)
# --> ['aaaa8', 'ccc8', 'dddddd8', 'aaaa8', 'hsd', 'ccc8', 'fdsf', 'ccc8', 'dddddd8']
```